# perforce web client throws error "P4CHARSET must be set in order to connect to a unicode server"

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I use perforce as sourcesafe, my desktop client is working fine.
I just install P4Web, perforce web client and when I try to open a file I get the following error:

> P4CHARSET must be set in order to connect to a unicode server

I already add P4CHARSET registry key set to utf8 under 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\perforce\environment

What more can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set it for the P4Web service.  Check out this KB article:

http://kb.perforce.com/article/231/p4web-as-a-windows-service

There are examples of setting other parameters like the port number; you can follow those guidelines for setting P4CHARSET.

you need to run the following line on cmd:

```
p4 set -S "Perforce Web" P4CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to run: p4 set -S "Perforce Web" P4CHARSET=utf8